# Django - How to access prefetch_related fields?

Tags: django

```
students = Student.objects.prefetch_related('user__applications').all()

students.user__applications # Error
```

So a student has a foreign key to a User object which is associated with a list of applications. But how do I access the list of applications from the Student object?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @dfundako Yup, it never (to my knowledge) addresses this use case.. Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `prefetch_related` nor `select_related` change the way you access the related data; you do it via the fields or reverse relations, just as you would if you didn't use those methods.

In this case, you have a queryset composed of students; each one of those will have a `user` attribute, which gives a User object which in turn has an `applications` field which gives another queryset. So, for example:

```
students[0].user.applications.all()[0]
```

Comment: Why are you retrieving only the first application?

Comment: It was an example, you can get them all if you like.

Answer (score 1):

While `prefetch_related` doesn't change the way you access the related data, if you only care about the model at the end of the "joining chain" in a `prefetch_related` call, you can use [`QuerySet.union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union).

Something like this:

```
students = Student.objects.prefetch_related('user__applications').all()
application_qs_list = [student.user.applications.all() for student in students]
applications = application_qs_list[0].union(application_qs_list[1:])
```

By default, this will remove duplicate entries. If you want to change this behavior, you can pass `all=True` to `union()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `related_name` attribute set in your `ForeignKey` field in `Application` model  in order to call it from `Student` Model. For example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Application(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name="applications", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    """other fields"""
```

Then you can call it from your student model like this:

```
students = Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('applications')
```

You will have list of students. So you need to access each student object and then you can access that particular student's applications like this:

```
for student in students:
    app = student.applications
```

Comment: Right, so that's not going to work. It's not really a solution to change the model schema in order to fix related queries.

Comment: @Daniel has already given a solution based on your approach. But this is the right approach while creating a Foreign Key relationship. But if you know what to fetch from the database, you can always use `Model.objects.get(id=1)` and it will return not the list but the single object from the database. Then you can easily call `student.applications` on the instance to get that student's application.

Comment: yup, that's why i accepted his answer. What you are describing is a classic n+1 query problem which is unrealistic for large sets of data.