# Django: How can I change my code to access ForeignKey fields through 3 tables?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

I tried to get values with using three tables.

```
cart_c = Cart.objects.select_related('item').filter(user=2)
context = {'cart_c': cart_c}
```

I got QuerySet, 'cart_c', but I could not refer ItemPhoto.photo from 'cart_c'.

So, I made three tables joined with prefetch_related().

```
items = Item.objects.prefetch_related('item_photo', 'cart_item').filter(cart__user=2)
context = {'items': items}
```

But, I do not have any good idea to access ItemPhoto.photo and Cart.quantity except this.

```
items[0].cart_item.values()[0].get('quantity')
# Or [i.quantity for item in items for i in item.cart_item.all()]
```

I think this way is not proper and sophisticated to use in Django Template System.

It's complicated I think.

I found [a relative question in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258861/django-how-to-access-prefetch-related-fields), and one of the answers is same like code I wrote.

```
items[0].cart_item.all()[0]
```

Could anyone teach me how I should change and write code to send QuerySet or dictionary to Django Template to access Item.name, Item.price, ItemPhoto.photo and Cart.quantity with using three tables, Item, ItemPhoto and Cart?

Thanks.

models.py(omitted)

```
class Item(models.Model): # Product
    name = models.CharField("item_name", max_length=255, blank=False, default="")
    price = models.DecimalField("price",
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00, 
        blank=False,
    )


class ItemPhoto(models.Model): # Photo
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="item_photo", verbose_name="item_id",)
    photo = models.ImageField("item_photo", blank=True, 
        upload_to=get_itemimage_path)


class Cart(models.Model): # Order
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        verbose_name="user",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,
        related_name="cart_user",)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name="item_id", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="cart_item", null=False,)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("quantity", default=0)
```

*Python: 3.9 / Django 4.1*

Comment: Are you trying to display the item list in the template, or the cart and it's associated items? I assume you mean the latter, but your question's wording is a little confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I am sorry for making you confused. As you mentioned, basically, I wanted to have the cart and associated items. But I had no idea to access to ItemPhoto.photo by starting with Cart.objects, so I tried to take a different approach through Item. If I can have a QuerySet from Cart.objects..., it is much better for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have as `Cart`, should actually be `CartItem`. A model that represents the quantity of each item that a user can put in their actual `Cart`. In my answer, I'm referring it as `CartItem`.

You can access Item's attributes, its photo, and cart quantity in the following manner:

For **Postgres**, we've used `ArrayAgg` to combine the list of photos per item and annotate it on the `CartItem` object:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

cart_item_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=2).select_related('item').annotate(
    item_photos=ArrayAgg('item__item_photo__photo')
)

# You can then pass this in the context
context = {"cart_items": cart_item_qs}
```

Finally, in the template, you can iterate on your `cart_items` like:

```
{% for cart_item in cart_items %}
    {{ cart_item.item.name }} - {{ cart_item.item.price }}
    {% for photo in cart_item.item_photos %}
        <img src="{{ photo.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

For **MySQL**, we can use [`Func` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to apply `GROUP_CONCAT` SQL function to concatenate all `photo` from `CartItem`

```
cart_item_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=2).select_related('item').annotate(
    item_photos=models.Func(models.Value('GROUP_CONCAT'), models.Value('item_photo.photo'), function='GROUP_CONCAT')
)

# You can then pass this in the context
context = {"cart_items": cart_item_qs}
```

To parse this in the template, you'll do something like this:

```
{% for cart_item in cart_items %}
    {{ cart_item.item.name }} - {{ cart_item.item.price }}
    {% for photo in cart_item.photos.split(",") %}
        <img src="{{ photo }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the `GROUP_CONCAT` is not supported, then you can also write this query using `Subquery` in Django.

PS: You can use [django-versatilimagefield](https://pypi.org/project/django-versatileimagefield/) for storing your images. It provides a lot of additional functionality for storing and retrieving images in different dimensions.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your solution looks wonderful! Very Sophisticated and clean. But please let me ask you. In your solution, you use postgres function, ArrayAgg, but I use MySQL and SQlite3. What should I use substitute for **from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg**? I searched the substitute, but I could not find. 
PS. Thank you for letting me know the package, django-versatilimagefield. I didn't know that. I will try this asap.

Comment: Glad that you find that useful @K-Yuuma I've added MySQL equivalent which calls `GROUP_CONCAT` function. If it's not supported, you can use Subquery from Django. If this answer helped you, you can upvote/accept it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I confirmed and it worked well. I hadn't seen the way like your solution. I like your way, so I will use from now on. I really appreciate your great help. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to know that @K-Yuuma. You can upvote the solution then as it will be an indicator to rest of the community that it works.

Comment: I am so sorry, but, could you let me ask you one more thing? When I use SQLite3, Func and 'GROUP_CONCAT' don't work. So I followed your advice and tried to use SubQuery like `cart_item_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=2).select_related('item').annotate(
 item_photos=Subquery(ItemPhoto.objects.all()))` and got `FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`. I struggled, but I am not familier with using Subquery. Would you mind teaching me? Thanks.

Comment: PS. I tried to click △ button many times, but StackOverFlow says 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' So, after I got 15 reputations, I sure will upvote. I am sorry.

Comment: Hi @K-Yuuma that's not how Subquery works. Please refer to Django docs here, explaining the SubQuery expression with OuterRef: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: I finally did!! Thank you so much. My solution is `subqs = ItemPhoto.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('item'))
 cart_item_subqs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=user).select_related('item').annotate(
   item_photos=Subquery(subqs.values('photo')),
 )
 [photo for cart_item in cart_item_subqs for photo in cart_item.item_photos]` I can say I developed myself thanks to you. If I lived in your place, I would treat dishes in a good restaurant. lol Thank you so much!! It's beyond description!!